# Cookie (document.cookie)

Tags: javascript, cookies

Iep, i have a problem, its the first time that im working with cookies and i was trying to save them.
The question is that only the 2 first values are saved, in this case "nombre" and "tuValor". If i do "alert(document.cookie)" the other values dont apear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function guardar() {
Nombre = "Empire";
tuValor = "F"+food;
tuValor2 = "w"+wood;
caduca = "31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 GMT";
document.cookie = Nombre+"="+tuValor+tuValor2+"expire= "+caduca ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are the values of `food` and `wood`? How exactly do the "disappear", what exactly is alerted?

Comment: "food" and "wood" are variables with numbers.
The alert returns this= "Empire=F1".
If i change the order of values for example "tuValor2" in the place of "tuValor1" the  alert returns this= "Empire=W3".

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolon before `expire`.

It goes like this:

```
document.cookie="my_cookie=empireWh4t3v3r;expires=Thu, 23 Apr 2020 15:37:15 GMT;"
```